# How to mount Ghost on a subdirectory in express

Tags: node.js, express, ghost-blog

I have a an existing website built with express and I would like to add a "/blog" powered by Ghost. I've added Ghost to my dependencies, installed and configured the urls in Ghosts config to localhost:3000/blog, but now I'm having trouble.

In my app.js I've added the following lines:

```
var blog = require('./routes/blog');
app.use('/blog', blog);
```

My blog.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ghost = require('ghost');
ghost().then(function (ghostServer) {
    ghostServer.start();
});

router.get('/', ghost);

module.exports = router;
```

I'm pretty sure blog.js is incorrect.

Comment: have you had a look at [this article](https://ghost.org/forum/installation/16995-using-ghost-on-an-existing-express-website/)?

Comment: Yes, I read that. Thanks though. I think it's related.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: This article about [using ghost as middleware](https://rogerstringer.com/2015/09/07/ghost-express-middleware/) could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Node is very limited to do is, for cases when `ghost` is not configurable as `express` middleware, which I believe is the case here.

That leaves you with Loadbalancers and DNS as solutions to this problem. On something like `HAPRoxy` or `Nginx` you could make those recirects on the `/blog` route, would need to cater for scripts that the HTML requires to load and to redirect them too.

This might be also better practice since you seperate the concerns.